# Set screen orientation for launch screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

I'm working on an app using flutter that only has as valid device orientations landscape left, landscape right and portrait (set in: Xcode > Deployment Info > Device Orientation). The problem I'm having is only with iOS, not android.

The app mainly works with landscapes orientations, we use portrait only when a user opens the camera to take a photo, only for that screen, nothing else.

What I want to achieve:
While working on this feature which was to allow users to take a photo of themselves as an option to add a profile photo, I had to enable as a valid device orientation portrait (as I said, only for the sake of this feature/screen). But when I enabled portrait mode, splash screen which is supposed to be displayed only in landscape left or right as it did before, it's now being displayed in portrait mode and it looks horrible...

How can I set splash screen orientation only to landscape left or right?

Should I assign a key command to the launch screen view controller? Add something to AppDelegate?

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this was to get the appdelegate:

`@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate`

which goes in yout `@main` `App` file and then in the AppDelegate file

```
import UIKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight.union(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeLeft)
    }
}
```

The above code will allow both landscapes - which may be useful depending on which way the person is holding their phone